# Music folder localized name doesn't work if it's a symlink

Tags: windows, symbolic-link

My music folder is on `D:` and the Music folder in the user folder (`C:`) is a junction point to that folder. The `desktop.ini` in the real folder is:

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
LocalizedResourceName=@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-21790
InfoTip=@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-12689
IconResource=%SystemRoot%\system32\imageres.dll,-108
IconFile=%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll
IconIndex=-237
ConfirmFileOp=0
[ViewState]
Mode=
Vid=
FolderType=Music
```

The junction point (in the user folder) uses the correct icon (specified by the real folder's `desktop.ini`), but for some reason, the `LocalizedResourceName` in the same `desktop.ini` is ignored, and the junction point's name reads "Music" instead of the Russian "Музыка". That isn't a big problem, since I know English well, but that's bothering and breaks consistency with other user folder subfolders, like Documents. So, how to I apply `LocalizedResourceName` to a junction point?

OS version is Windows 10 Professional
The real (`D:`) music folder is an OwnCloud sync folder

Comment: Did you try to duplicate `desktop.ini` inside the music folder is on D?

Comment: @harrymc It's there already. I don't understand what you mean anyway: `desktop.ini` is shared for both the symlink and what it refers to.

Comment: Question updated to inform that I use junction points instead of symlinks.